# Xcodeで"Could not insert new outlet connection: could not find any information > for the class named view controller"

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcodeで割引計算を作ろうとしています。
Storyboadにレイアウトされたティストフィールドやボタンと、
ソースコードを紐づけていきたいのですが、
テキストフィールドをcontrolキーを押しながら選択して、
Assistant Editorのソースコードへドラッグ&ドロップをすると、
下記エラーが出ます。

エラー内容

> Could not insert new outlet connection: could not find any information
>   for the class named view controller

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

試した事
・Finder > ライブラリ > Developer > Xcode > DerivedData > …のファイル削除
・プロダクトのクリーン ⌘＋Shift＋K
・キャッシュを消す $ rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode
・Xcode再起動

以上を試しましたが解決できてません。
他にどのような解決方法があるでしょうか。
宜しくお願いします。

環境

> macOS HighSierra macOS HighSierra 10.13.6
>   Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000)

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました。

選択していたファイルが間違ってました。

ViewController.swiftを選択して、ドラッグ&ドロップできましたので、
宜しくお願いします。